# Problem with fitting Moving average into curve

Tags: python, curve-fitting, curve, moving-average, astronomy

I have a problem with the Moving average function in Python. I tried using a couple of methods but they didn't work. Moving average that I used before work well on my light curve, but problem occurs with phased diagram:
[Phase diagram with fitted moving average](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uETMF.png)

I don't know why it's not working properly. Here is a code I use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('phase.txt', dtype='float,float', names=["Time","Flux"])
t = data["Time"]
flux = data["Flux"]

def movingaverage(interval, window_size):
   window = np.ones(int(window_size))/float(window_size)
   return np.convolve(interval, window,'same')

av = movingaverage(flux, 10)

plt.plot(t,flux,"C0.", ms=2)
plt.plot(t,av,"r")
plt.show
```

I would expect something like this:
[fitted moving average](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxIoo.png)

Here is my file with values in two columns:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IQScAo8iduv90wuaor8o9eJT85qBpKY4/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that your time values and the corresponding flux values are not properly sorted. Time values should be ascending.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('phase.txt', dtype='float,float', names=["Time","Flux"])
t = data["Time"]
flux = data["Flux"]

# sort time values in ascending order
sort_idx = t.argsort()
t = t[sort_idx]

# sort flux values accordingly
flux = flux[sort_idx]


def movingaverage(interval, window_size):
   window = np.ones(int(window_size))/float(window_size)
   return np.convolve(interval, window,'same')

av = movingaverage(flux, 10)

plt.plot(t,flux,"C0.", ms=2)
plt.plot(t,av,"r")
plt.ylim([0.95, 1.05]) # zoom in a little
plt.show()
```

Does this yield the result you were expecting?

---

I have tried both, only sorting time values as well as sorting time and flux values.

Only sorting time values:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Sorting time values and flux values:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Which one looks more plausible to you?

Comment: Not exactly, beacase after sorting by time it turns back to light curve, when the average I need should be fitted to phase diagram of that light curve. But still, probably that time column is the problem in this method

Comment: @Ustregal Ok, I am not quite sure what light curves or phased diagrams refer to in your case. But in any case, you should use sorted time values (and data points sorted accordingly). Otherwise, the output of the moving average is meaningless.

Comment: I agree with @Flursch, sort both.
The lower one of the suggested results should be ok.

Comment: Yes! the second one is almost exactly what I needed. (First one is my light curve and the second one is a phase diagram of that light curve) Now I just have to change window size as @alec_djinn said. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your data is quite scattered. Consider averaging over a larger window.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('phase.txt', sep=' ', names=["Time","Flux"]).sort_values(by='Time')
df['MA_10'] = df.Flux.rolling(window=10).mean()
df['MA_100'] = df.Flux.rolling(window=100).mean()

plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))
plt.scatter(df.Time, df.Flux, c='blue')
plt.plot(df.Time, df.MA_10, c='red')
plt.plot(df.Time, df.MA_100, c='black')
plt.ylim([0.95, 1.05])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Now that's the second thing I have to change in my code. Thank you!